# How do I check if the cached version of a file exists with htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using the following code to rewrite requests for pages toward the gzipped, cached static versions of dynamically generated PHP pages. I have two issues:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cache/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.)(.*?)/?$ /cache/$1/$1$2.html.gz [L]
```

1. First, I only want this rule to take effect if the cached file does indeed exist.
2. Second, I need to ensure that the browser is instructed that this is a gzipped file that should be unzipped, read and displayed and not something that should get downloaded like a file which is what is currently happening.

The url structure of the pages are as follows:

```
http://mydomain.com/newest-coupon-codes/
```

which needs to display the following page to the user without changing the address bar to the text:

```
http://mydomain.com/cache/n/newest-coupon-codes.html.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution #1:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html\.gz$">
  ForceType text/html
  Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cache/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.)(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond cache/%1/%1%2.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.)(.*?)/?$ /cache/$1/$1$2.html.gz [L]
```

#### Solution #2:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html\.gz$">
  ForceType text/html
  Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cache/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.)(.*?)/?$ [E=CACHE:"cache/$1/$1$2.html.gz",NE]
RewriteCond %{ENV:CACHE} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.)(.*?)/?$ /cache/$1/$1$2.html.gz [E=!CACHE,L]
```

Comment: @NicholasCardot - **Please remove ALL your comments above, as they are now irrelevant**